# Mechanical properties of solids

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, elasticity

Young's modulus of bone for tensile is $16× 10^9 N/m^2$ and for compressive is $9  × 10^9 N/m^2$

Why is  tensile Young's modulus is more than for compressive?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reference for those numbers? They seem to be wrong by several orders of magnitude. You may be confusing tensile and compressive *strength* with Young's modulus.

Comment: @alephzero it is given in NCERT textbook of physics, I added screenshot

Comment: Your post says the Young's modulus is $16 \times 10^7$ but the table says $16 \times 10^9$. That's what was confusing me. But the NCERT tensile strength numbers are 10 times smaller than http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781461462545-c1.pdf (page 8 of the PDF).

Comment: @alephzero that was a typo , I just want to know why there is difference for two types

Comment: Related : https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/30498/

Answer (score 0):

The possible sources for difference are: 1) different sample materials (i.e. different bones studied); 2) different conditions (like water content in the bone etc.); 3) different methods used (e.g. [ultrasonic and mechanical results differ](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8429054)).

Other than that, for the same bone type measured with the same technique under same conditions [both values should be the same](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021929074900189).